# Stale data in first level cache

Tags: c#, nhibernate, orm

I have multiple sessions working in my database at the same time. (regular DB session and NHibernate session)

The first time when I get an Entity from the D.B. the entity is stored in the first level cache - identity map.

what happens if after the first query The entity changed outside the NH session? the data is stale.

```
session.Get<Cat>(1).Name == "Bar" // true
// different session trigger updated the cat name to "Foo"    
session.Get<Cat>(1).Name == "Bar" // true
```

Is there a way to sync NHibernate session to changes outside the session?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's easy:

```
session.Refresh(cat);
```

Comment: Correct and helpful as always... What about if the change happened before I refresh the object. I don't want to Write refresh every line to verify that the entity wasn't changed. Do you got anything for me?

Comment: Are you looking for an automatic refresh of all entities in all sessions every time there is a commit in any of them? You can do messaging (i.e. broadcast update messages to all session containers), but I'd use optimistic concurrency instead.

Comment: Just update those entities which have been changed in other session (not NH session). There is not need to refresh all the session identity map.

Comment: Yes, I meant updated entities. What kind of app is this? (desktop, web, other)

Comment: I don't think there's a good case to use `Refresh` in a web app. A request should usually take less than a second; using Refresh will kill your scalability completely. Use optimistic concurrency and transactions instead.